# Text flowing to next line

Tags: html, css

I have following in html:

```css
.horizontal-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.style-1 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 19px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #272d37;
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.style-2 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 295px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-div">
  <div class="style-1">Dummy QC</div>
  <div class="style-2">Some image</div>
</div>
```

What I observe is that 'Dummy QC' goes to next line, as:

[image]

What can be the solution to avoid it from going to next line?

Comment: do you really need to set a width to those containers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS white-space Property

```
.horizontal-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.style-1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #272d37;
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

flex-wrap will work. The problem occurs only when resizing the page to go below your declared width. get rid of the width, or use a media query for small screen/size rules. tested and this works. will force the text to stay on one line.

Answer (score -2):

Set overflow property to div you would, also select value that fits you most out of those:

```
div.ex1 {
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.ex2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.ex3 {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.ex4 {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This only changes what the wrapping looks like. It doesn't avoid wrapping.

Comment: use white-space property then